# Crystal Reports keeps asking for username/password

Tags: crystal-reports

A different user is trying to run an existing crystal report.  They are able to access the report but when they click refresh it is asking for a username and password to connect.  The data source location is defined and when I run it doesn't ask me for a username and password.  The user I'm trying to run this from is a generic username.  I don't want it to keep prompting for this when they run it so what needs to be done?  Other users run this existing report without any issues when signing in as themselves.  What's the easiest way to fix this?

Comment: Hello again :) I've still been working with Crystal Reports recently so I could probably help you with this. Are you using Crystal Report Viewer or how is the report viewed?

Comment: Hi and thanks for assisting!They gave them a full license and run by accessing Crystal Reports, pull up the report, click refresh which runs the report and allows them to print it directly to their local printer.

Comment: Are you using a database for the data source and if so do they have the connection set up?

Comment: I figured out I can get it to at least connect now by changing the connection type from ODBC(RDO) to OLE(ADO) and then it will accept the username/password as opposed to a Failed Login message.  It still keeps asking me the username/password and I'd like to store that with the connection so users don't need to keep entering it each time they run the report.

Comment: I don't think it can store passwords, as that would be dangerous, but there are some suggestions here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/2029712

Comment: OK thanks.  I'm having the users switch to their own logins before running the report and then it works just fine.  They didn't want to have to switch but I agree using a generic user for this purpose isn't a good idea since it provides access to protected patient information.